# How to commit changes to local SQL DB In Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2015, localdb

I am new to working with databases. I made a simple form app to display this data table however, I can't get the data into the database so that the form displays it. I initially had only 1 employee listed here and he shows up in my application. I just added the last 3 employees into this table view but if I run the app, only the original employee (id 1) shows up. How do I commit the last 3 employees' info into the database? I Googled some info on this and found a `select * from dbo.EmployeeInfo` query and ran it, it displays the employee info right but it doesn't seem to change the database with the new info. Thank you.

[image: My database table info]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a form with a GridView, and binded it with a Datasource it shows me the data in the form u showed above...

Added some textboxes for input......

The code below shows how it binds the datasource with the gridview and how you would insert data permanently using input from textboxes at a button click event

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // using a gridview by binding the dataset with it at form load
        //It creates the table for you with the relevant columns
        //and fills it with this line of code
        this.employeesTableAdapter.Fill(this.practiceDBDataSet.Employees);

    }

    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //on add  user button click
        //I access the tableadpater created by the dataset to be accessed by the gridview
        //the txt.... represents my fields names according to the database
        employeesTableAdapter.Insert(txtName.Text, txtSurname.Text, txtAge.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text));
    }
```

And then the txt.... are in place for the data required by the Database, where you would be getting your input from.........

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck here too.
What I did was -
1) Updated the values and after updating the last values, I pressed Enter

It seems to work for me.
Enter button on keyboard makes life simple. :)